# How to compute the partial derivative of the cost function of mean regularized multi task learning?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Background: This is the costfunction of [Mean Regularized Multi Task Learning](http://www.public.asu.edu/~jye02/Software/MALSAR/MTL-SDM12.pdf).
This is a typical linear regression learning model, with the only difference being that there's multiple instances of trainings going on at the same time. So X has an additional 3rd dimension and W and Y a 2nd dimension.
X is training data, Y is targets, W is weights, m is number of tasks (3rd dimension), d is number of features, n is number of examples.

$X\in R^{n_i\times d \times m}$,
$Y\in R^{n_i\times m }$,
$W\in R^{d \times m}$

[image]

Question:
Given the cost function

$$
J =\min_W \frac{1}{2}||XW-Y||_F^2+\lambda\sum_{i=1}^m||W_i-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{s=1}^mW_s||^2_2
$$
What is
$\frac{\partial}{\partial W}J$?

I need to calculate the partial derivatives that can be used with steepest  gradient descent optimization algorithm. I was thinking of calculating the derivative both with respect to a single weight, and the whole matrix. See my answer for my calculations so far.

Comment: What is $F$? Do you know how to take the partial derivatives of the first term, second term, or neither?

Comment: @Douglas Zare I dont know either but asked on math http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304878/how-to-calculate-v-22

Comment: I don't think $||.||_F$ means the Frobenius norm here, which is what several people guessed on math.stackexchange. Check the link you gave. At least one later slide mentions $F$, but didn't completely specify it.

Comment: @Douglas It looks like the $L^2$ norm on pp 54 and 69 (where it is specifically called that).  That's equivalent to the Frobenius norm in those cases (where it appears to be applied to vectors).  At the bottom of p. 26 it's clearly the Frobenius norm of a matrix.

Comment: @whuber: I assumed that $F$ had something to do with the $F$ on pages 46-48, "$m\times k$ orthogonal cluster indicator matrix." But perhaps that's just a coincidence.

Comment: @DouglasZare I think F is to do with Frobenius norm.

Comment: You say $X$ is a 3 dimensional "matrix"  which is impossible, so what do you mean by $XW$?  And by $n_i$ do you mean there are different numbers of observations for each response?

Comment: @probabilityislogic you are right, X is a tensor. And yes, different number of observations

Answer (score 3):

Just some general advice

- try to limit the indexation where possible, and use matrix algebra
- As the dimension of $Y_i$ varies with $i$ best not to store as a matrix.  Treat $i$ separately.
- Alternatively, you could define Y as one very long vector $Y=(Y_1^T,\dots,Y_m^T)^T$.  Similarly, $X$ would have $\sum_{i=1}^{m}n_i$ rows and $d$ columns.  But then $W$ needs to be redefined as the driect sum $W=\oplus_{i=1}^{m}W_i$.  But then $W$ now has structural zeros.  Too complicated to work with...
- don't use indices more than once.  For example you use $w_{j,k}$ and also use $j,k$ as summation variables. Should use $w_{r,s}$ instead

So I would write your cost function as
$$J=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_iW_i-Y_i)^T (X_iW_i-Y_i) +\lambda (W_i-\overline{W})^T (W_i-\overline{W})$$
Where $\overline{W}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}W_i$
Now using the chain rule we have $\frac{\partial e^Te}{\partial W_r}= 2\frac{\partial e}{\partial W_r} e$

So you have
$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial W_r} =X_r^T (X_rW_r-Y_r) +2\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left(\frac{\partial W_i}{\partial W_r}- \frac{\partial 
\overline{W} }{\partial W_r}\right)(W_i-\overline{W})$$
 $$ =X_r^T (X_rW_r-Y_r) +2\lambda (W_r-\overline{W})$$

This is not the answer you have.

**update**

One way you can re-express the equations is by setting $ X=\oplus_{i=1}^mX_i $  (which has $\sum_{i=1}^mn_i $ rows and $ dm $ colums, and $ w=(W_1^T,\dots, W_m^T)^T $ and $ Y=(Y_1^T,\dots, Y_m^T)^T $.  We can also re-express the penalty term as $\sum_{i=1}^m(W_i-\overline {W})^T (W_i-\overline {W})=w^Tw-m\overline {W}^T\overline {W} =w^T (I-m^{-1}G^TG) w $ where $ G$ is the $ d\times md $ matrix which calculates the totals for $ w $.  So the $ k $ th row of $ G $ has ones in columns $k, d+k, 2d+k, \dots, (m-1) d+k $ and zeroes everywhere else.  We can also write the other factor as $\frac{1}{2}(Y-Xw)^T (Y-Xw) $.  Hence an explicit solution is given as

$$\hat {w}=\left [X^TX +2\lambda (I-m^{-1} G^TG)\right]^{-1} X^TY $$

It will probably be more efficient to implement by first use the woodbury matrix identity, as $ X^TX $ is a block- diagonal matrix.

Comment: so you calculated it with respect to Wr, which is one column of W. If you calculate it with respect the whole W you would get my batch gradient result and if you calculate it with respect to a single w element, you would get my online gradient, wouldn't you? I don't see the difference. I might not have been too precise with my notation, i.e. should have used X transpose before, not after in order for it to make mathematical sense. Let me know if you think there would be major differences in our implementations.

Comment: anyway, I'll give you the bounty for taking the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I came to this conclusion. Can anyone verify it please?

---

Online gradient descent:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{j,k}}J =\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{j,k}}\frac{1}{2}||XW-Y||_F^2+\lambda\sum_{i=1}^m||W_i-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{s=1}^mW_s||^2_2
$$
let $
 z_{i,k} = \sum_{j=1}^dx_{i,j,k}w_{j,k} - y_{i,k}
$
$$
=\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{j,k}}\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{k}}|z_{i,k}|^2}\right)^2+\lambda\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^d|w_{j,k}-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{s=1}^mw_{j,s}|^2}\right)^2
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{j,k}}\frac{1}{2}{\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{k}}z_{i,k}^2}+\lambda\sum_{k=1}^m(\sum_{j=1}^d(w_{j,k}-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{s=1}^mw_{j,s})^2)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{j,k}}J= \sum_{i=1}^{n_{k}}((\sum_{j=1}^dx_{i,j,k}w_{j,k}-y_{i,k}) x_{i,j,k})+\lambda2(w_{j,k}-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{s=1}^mw_{j,s})(1-\frac{1}{m})
$$

---

Batch gradient descent
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W}J= (XW-Y)X + 2\lambda\sum_{i=1}^m(W_i-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{s=1}^mW_s)
$$

Comment: How did the weights suddenly acquire two subscripts in some places and three in another when in the question they have only one?

Comment: @whuber So I was trying to computer the partial derivative with respect one weight. In the original question W was a matrix. Let me update the description

Comment: First work it out in the case where all dimensions are $1$, so that $x$, $w$, and $y$ can be considered numbers: that will show you some of the missing pieces and why you don't need the absolute values.

Comment: @whuber why would the absolute values disappear?

Comment: There are no absolute values to begin with because your function is a sum of squares of things and the derivative of $x^2$ with respect to $x$ is $2x$, not $2|x|$. One mistake you have made is to express these sums of squares in terms of square roots and absolute values, neither of which is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @whuber I see, so why are there absolute values in the definition here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304878/how-to-calculate-v-22

Comment: Because that respondent was (implicitly) quoting a more general formula used for $p$-norms in which arbitrary powers (given by the value $p$) are summed. For this to work as a norm when $p$ is not even, the absolute value must be used. In your case there's no need for that general formula; all it does is to complicate the computation of the derivatives.

Comment: You tell me--would you prefer to compute the partial derivative using the Chain Rule applied to the square of a square root instead of just computing directly?  But you're getting way off track here: this has turned into a problem that's purely about differentiation. Would you like us to just close it as off topic or migrate it to the Math site for you?

Comment: @whuber I don't know what I prefer. I just want the correct answer. Its not about personal preference. So can you please suggest the correct solution? Should I just omit the absolute values? Also, for gradient descent, is it better to derive wrt to one weight or the whole weight matrix?

Comment: @whuber ok I see what you mean. Is it correct now? Also, for gradient descent is it better to derive wrt one weight or the whole matrix?

Comment: Anyway, although I think it is correct now, I found a way to let matlab do the derivation for me with symbolic variables. So not that important now.